# How can I efficiently activate an edge attribute at multiple times in a networkDynamic object in R?

Tags: r, networking, import, sna, statnet

I want to construct a `networkDynamic` object in R from transaction data where each line represents a contribution by a person to a document. Multiple contributions should be represented as an increase in edge weight instead of creating multiple edges.

The following code snippets should be reproducible in RStudio easily to see the problem.

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman"); library("pacman")
pacman::p_load(network, networkDynamic, ndtv, lubridate)

stTransac <- "
'person', 'document', 'weight', 'instantId'
'A',      'a1',       '3',      '1'
'A',      'a1',       '15',     '2'
'A',      'a1',       '100',    '3'
'B',      'a1',       '20',     '10'
'C',      'a1',       '30',     '12'
"
dfTransac <- read.csv(text = stTransac, sep = "," , quote = '\'' , strip.white = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

net <- network.initialize(0, directed = TRUE, bipartite = 3)

add.vertices.networkDynamic(net, 3, vertex.pid = c("A","B","C"))
add.vertices.networkDynamic(net, 1, vertex.pid = "a1")

net %v% "vertex.names" <- c(c("A","B","C"), "a1")
set.network.attribute(net,'vertex.pid','vertex.names')
set.network.attribute(net,'edge.pid','edge.names')

add.edges.networkDynamic(net,
                         tail = get.vertex.id(net, c("A","B","C")),
                         head = get.vertex.id(net, "a1"),
                         edge.pid = paste0(c("A","B","C"), "->a1"))

activate.edges(net,
               e = get.edge.id(net, paste0(dfTransac[["person"]], "->a1")),
               at = dfTransac$instantId)
```

Up to now, everything works as expected (if you skip the `activate.edge.attribute` block below and jump directly to the last block, you will see in the animation that edges are activated at times 1,2,3,10,12.) However, when using the `activate.edge.attribute` function intuitively in the same way as the `activate.edges` function, for the first edge the weight attribute is only initialized at `3` with a value of `100`. The earlier two weight values are dropped.

```
activate.edge.attribute(net,
                        prefix = "weight",
                        value = dfTransac$weight,
                        e = get.edge.id(net, paste0(dfTransac[["person"]], "->a1")),
                        at = dfTransac$instantId)
```

I could iterate over the transaction data frame, but I suppose this will not scale too well:

```
by(dfTransac, 1:nrow(dfTransac), function(row) {
    net <<- activate.edge.attribute(net,
               prefix = "weight",
               value = row[["weight"]],
               e = get.edge.id(net, paste0(row[["person"]], "->", row[["document"]])),
               at = row[["instantId"]])
})
```

This last block renders the animation...

```
reconcile.vertex.activity(net = net, mode = "encompass.edges", edge.active.default = FALSE)

compute.animation(net, slice.par = list(start = 1, end = 13, interval = 1, aggregate.dur = 1, rule = "any"))
render.animation(net)
ani.replay()
```

What is the correct and efficient way to set the weight attribute `at` multiple different timestamps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partially for efficiency reasons, the attribute activate code cannot activate multiple spells per vertex/edge. As the documentation says:

> ... it is possible to use one function call to activate multiple
>   values on multiple vertices with a different activity time on each
>   vertex, but it is not possible to activate multiple values at multiple
>   times on a single vertex with one call.

I would recommend the following syntax for creating your network with the `networkDynamic()` constructor function, which has the option to import attributes at the same time.

```
# re-arrange the data.frame column order to an edge.spell format, 
# duplicating the time to use for onset and terminus
input<-dfTransac[,c(4,4,1,2,3)]

# convert the ids to numeric
ids<-unique(c(dfTransac$person,dfTransac$document))
input[,3]<-match(input[,3],ids)
input[,4]<-match(input[,4],ids)
input
  instantId instantId.1 person document weight
1         1           1      1        4      3
2         2           2      1        4     15
3         3           3      1        4    100
4        10          10      2        4     20
5        12          12      3        4     30

# initialize a base network with the appropriate characteristics
net<-network.initialize(length(ids),bipartite=3)
# copy in the vertex names
network.vertex.names(net)<-ids

# use the networkDynamic constructor, telling it to create dynamic attributes
netDyn <- networkDynamic(net,edge.spells = input,
+                          create.TEAs = TRUE,edge.TEA.names = 'weight')

Activated TEA edge attributes:  weightCreated net.obs.period to describe network
 Network observation period info:
  Number of observation spells: 1 
  Maximal time range observed: 1 until 12 
  Temporal mode: continuous 
  Time unit: unknown 
  Suggested time increment: NA 

# print out the attributes structure for edge 1 to double check
get.edge.attribute(netDyn,'weight.active',unlist=FALSE)[[1]]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 3

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 15

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 100


[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    3
```

So we can see that the first edge now has the expected 3 values for 'weight'.  Note the `networkDynamic()` has to do similar looping to appropriately attach the dynamic attributes, but at least it is all under the hood.